# std::size_t or std::vector<Foo>::size_type?

Tags: c++, stl, c++98, size-t, size-type

When I loop on a `std::vector<Foo>` (or every container having random access iterator) I use an unsigned integer variable `i`. If I want to respect the norm, should I use `std::size_t` or the type given by the container itself : `std::vector<Foo>::size_type` ?

If I chose `std::size_t` (for readability reasons), can I be sure that every implementation of every container in `std` namespace uses `std::size_t` as `size_type` ?

Note : I use C++98 only (for compatibility reasons).

Comment: No you can't be sure. If you want to avoid a possible narrowing conversion, use the container provided type.

Comment: One fun thing you could have is `size_t` be a typedef of `unsigned long` and `std::vector::size_type` could be `unsigned long long` on a 64 bit Linux machine.  Both are 64 bits wide and will have the same range but they are not the same type.  ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06c88c51b0cf219b))

Comment: You could use a template class that choose which type to use depending on whether or not ``std::size_t`` and ``std::vector<T>::size_type`` have the same size (I can't try right now to implement it but I'm pretty sure it's doable).

Comment: @NathanOliver : originally, I have this reflexion because I wrongly used `unsigned long int` everywhere (ok with gcc, `std::size_t` is `unsigned long int`). And now I have compatibility problem while porting to Windows with intel compilers where `std::size_t` is `unsigned long long int`. :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not *necessarily* true that `std::vector<Foo>::size_type` is the same as `std::size_t`. This is true even for C++11.

But personally I use `std::size_t` for a `std::vector` index irrespective of the type.

You could always use a static assertion if you're feeling particularly diligent. Obviously `static_assert` is a later addition beyond what's in C++98, but in that standard you could use something like

```
static char wrong_size_1[1 + sizeof(std::size_t) - sizeof(std::vector<Foo>::size_type)];

static char wrong_size_2[1 - sizeof(std::size_t) + sizeof(std::vector<Foo>::size_type)];
```

which would induce compile time failures if type types are not the same size.

Comment: Actually, I already use static asserts with boost. Good idea !

Comment: Wow. Boost still support C++98! They are good eggs, you know.

Comment: I use boost 1.57 with GCC 4.4.7 without any (known) problem. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> can I be sure that every implementation of every container in std namespace uses `std::size_t` as `size_type`?

No, you can not. However in practice, you can trust that `std::size_t` is big enough for a vector or any other container based on a single array because

> `size_t` can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).

Comment: The maximum size of an object could very well be way more then the maximum `size_type` of the vector. The range for `std::vector<>::type` is only 0 to `numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / sizeof(T)` when `T` is what's held in the vector. The worry is a possible narrowing conversion I'd say.

Comment: @StoryTeller I would worry if your integer was too small to index the objects of the vector. `std::size_t` is at least as big as it needs to be, so it can represent any index. At worst it wastes a tiny bit of memory.

Comment: If it's too small you'll have unreachable elements. If it's too large you "wrap around" and possibly modify elements in the wrong places. I think one is an easier bug to catch than the other. Narrowing conversions are more than a bit evil.

Comment: @StoryTeller where do you get this value that "wraps around"? Since it's bigger than fits in `size_type`, there is no way it is going to be a valid index, and so there is no way you are going to get the element. Using `size_type` won't make solving the bug easier, it just moves the point of wrap around to another piece of code.

Comment: "No way it will be a valid index". Except C++ will happily preform an implicit narrowing conversion. Which for unsigned integers is well defined as modulo 2 to some power. Hence the wrapping.