# Guarantee that std::container::size_type is a std::size_t

Tags: c++, stl, c++03, size-t, size-type

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45168636/3378179), I decided to use `std::size_t` as `size_type` for every containers, for obvious readability reasons. I know it's theorically possible that `std::container<T>::size_type` is not `std::size_t`, but I assume it's not the case on my current and future configurations.

However, in order to avoid wicked bugs, I check the types are the same when I use them. For example:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_same< std::vector<double>::size_type , std::size_t >::value);
std::vector<double> x;
/* fill x */
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) { /* do something */ }
```

Another place in the code, I use a `std::vector<long int>`, then I also check:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_same< std::vector<long int>::size_type , std::size_t >::value);
```

And then, oh no! I use `std::vector<std::list<std::string>*>` and `std::vector<std::list<double*>*>`, then I check:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_same< std::vector<std::list<std::string>*>::size_type , std::size_t >::value);
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_same< std::vector<std::list<double*>*>::size_type , std::size_t >::value);
```

Ok, I think you understand the problem. Ugly lines, difficult to maintain the code. It's a bad idea.

Then, my question is: **If I check `std::vector<any_common_type>::size_type` is a `std::size_t`, is there any chance that `std::vector<another_type>::size_type` is NOT `std::size_t` ? Is it enough to only check some common types in a separated file to be sure `std::container::size_type` is always `std::size_t` on my compiler ?**

*Note: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reasons.*

Comment: I agree with the 'Why?' It does not seem as though size_t can be smaller than vector<..>::size_type; so there is no risk that the size returned by the container will not fit in size_t.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question (I believe `size_type` doesn't change though), but if you ever happen to come across an implementation for which `size_t` is not big enough to contain all values of `size_type`, your compiler will issue a warning at the first comparison you attempt to perform.

Comment: As for the question if std::vector<T>::size_type could depend on the type: someone might try to use "unsigned short" as size_type  if sizeof(T) is large enough. I don't know if legal - or why anyone would bother with going for that trouble - but I see that as the most realistic scenario for different size_type.

Comment: Actually, it's not only a problem from a too small range, the range has to be the same to avoid bugs with, for example : `std::size_t p = x.find(...);` where `npos` is returned if not found. Typically, `npos` is `-1` (ie the max value of the type). If the range is not the same, it can cause very bad bugs (I tried, when I used `unsigned long int` instead of `std::size_t` ^^).

Comment: Yes, @Caduchon IF such functions exist - but container::find normally returns an iterator, not an index (and it doesn't exist in vector); so I don't see that as an issue with the standard containers.

Comment: ;-)  One problem with using `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` is that the extremely odd system where the assert would trigger is likely to not be supported by Boost.

Comment: @HansOlsson: it's the case for `std::string::find` ;-)

Comment: @BoPersson: hum... interesting remark. Actually, my goal is to obtain any warning or error to avoid silent bugs. I suppose in this case I'll be warn there is a problem ?

Comment: std::string is often seen as separate from the container-templates, and it contains a corresponding npos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you follow in your question seems to be the way to go, if you really need to do this.

However, I think you worry too much, since `size_t` can handle `size_type`.

If you ever find yourself in the unlikely situation where a platform implements `size_t` in a way that makes not big enough to contain all the values of `size_type`, then I am pretty sure that you will receive a compiler warning on any comparison you will attempt to perform.

['size_t' vs 'container::size_type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type) mentions:

> The standard containers define size_type as a typedef to
>   Allocator::size_type (Allocator is a template parameter), which for
>   std::allocator is typically defined to be size_t (or a compatible
>   type). So for the standard case, they are the same.

---

So, if I were you I would be confident about my compiler to lie in the typical case. However, if I did use non-standard containers, then I would bother to follow your - as you said ugly - approach, put it in a file and let it do its job in a hidden dark corner.